# Execute a shell command in C# to serial port mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to send a string over an serial port using C#.

I've accomplished to send this string via the terminal on my RaspBerry pi ( Raspbian) using the following command:

```
echo "TestMode On" > /dev/ttyAMC0
```

This works! but this is in the terminal only. What I would like to do is execute this specific command using C# What my current approach is is this :

```
public bool DoSomething(){
        MySerial = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyACM0");
        MySerial.Open();
        MySerial.ReadTimeout = 400;
        string s = "echo \"TestMode On\"\r";
        Log.Information(s);
        return SendData(s);
}
private bool SendData(string command)
    {
        MySerial.Write(command);
        return true;
    }
```

I'm Using Serilog to log information and in that console window I can see that the string really is:
echo "TestMode On"

What am I missing here?.

Thanks in advance,

Herm L.

Comment: Unix usually expects a `\n` as line end character, not `\r`. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yes I did. Even `\r\n` does not work

Comment: Surely you just need to send "TestMode on" not the echo, echo is the command line statement to send the ext.. you're doing that by your SendDate, so surely you just want "SendData("TestMode on")

Comment: Tried that approach from the beginning on. But the receiving end of the line does not respond at all. Only if I run the echo command mentioned earlier. Is there any other way maybe a bash command to talk to a serial port?

Answer (score 0):

`Echo` sends a newline by default and you would not include the quotes:

This line:

```
string s = "echo \"TestMode On\"\r";
```

Becomes:

```
string s = "TestMode On\n";
```

Comment: This is true indeed, but now I've tried to execute `echo TestMode On > /dev/ttyACM0` and it also worked, so this is not the problem

Comment: I've changed the encoding on the port from _ASCII_ to _UTF8_ this seems to fix it. I thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case is to change the encoding on the serial port from ASCII to UTF8. Apperantly this makes a difference here. Thanks everyone for their time and efforts!